# Prove $a^4+b^4+(a-b)^4=c^4+d^4+(c-d)^4$ if $a^2+b^2+(a-b)^2=c^2+d^2+(c-d)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

> if $a,b,c,d$ are positive real numbers and $$a^2+b^2+(a-b)^2=c^2+d^2+(c-d)^2$$
>   Prove $a^4+b^4+(a-b)^4=c^4+d^4+(c-d)^4$

*Things i have done:* from assumption $a^2+b^2+(a-b)^2=c^2+d^2+(c-d)^2$ I can conclude that $$a^2+b^2-ab=c^2+d^2-cd$$

Powering both sides to two gives $$a^4+b^4+a^2b^2-2a^3b-2ab^3=c^4+d^4+c^2d^2-2c^3d-2cd^3$$

And $$a^4+b^4+(a-b)^4=c^4+d^4+(c-d)^4 \rightarrow 2a^4+2b^4+6a^2b^2-2ab^3-2a^3b=2c^4+2d^4+6c^2d^2-2cd^3-2c^3d$$

I can't continue any more.

Comment: You forgot the $+2a^2b^2$ and $+2c^2d^2$ terms after you squared both sides. That's why it didn't work for you. Otherwise, what you did is no different from what Quang Hoang and I wrote below.

Comment: yes also another mistake in last line where it should be $-4ab^3$ and so others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that:
$$
a^4+b^4+(a-b)^4-c^4-d^4-(c-d)^4\\
=2(a^2-ab+b^2-c^2+cd-d^2)(a^2-ab+b^2+c^2-cd+d^2)
$$
so the result follows because you have proved the first term on the RHS is $0$.

Comment: thanks.you used [difference of two squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_of_two_squares) ,right?

Comment: Yes, $a^4+b^4+(a-b)^4=2(a^2-ab+b^2)^2$ and similarly for the other expression.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: 
$$\left(a^2+b^2+(a-b)^2\right)^2=2\left(a^4+b^4+(a-b)^4\right).$$
I wish I knew a smart, non brute-force, way to show that.